# Sprite collision Rectangles LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection, collision

I have a big problem with my sprite top collision. Here is my constructor

```
public CoolGuy(){
    full = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 98);
    bottom = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 15);
    top = new Rectangle(0, 83, 50, 15);
    left = new Rectangle(0, 15, 25, 68);
    right = new Rectangle(25, 15, 25, 68);

    texture = new Texture("data/coolguy1.png");
    sprite = new Sprite(texture);
    sprite.setSize(50, 98);
    this.setPosition(0, 0);
    velocity = 0;
}
```

here is my setPosition

```
public void setPosition(float x, float y){
        full.x = x;
        full.y = y;

        bottom.x = x;
        bottom.y = y;

        left.x = x;
        left.y = y + 15;

        right.x = x + 25;
        right.y = y + 15;

        top.x = x;
        top.y = y + 83;

        sprite.setPosition(x, y);

}
```

and this method returns number based top, bottom, right, left collisions.

```
public int hits(Rectangle r){

    if(left.overlaps(r)){
        return 2;
    }
    if(right.overlaps(r)){
        return 3;
    }

    if(top.overlaps(r)){
        return 4;
    }
    if(bottom.overlaps(r)){
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

and here in my main class I check collisions

```
for(GameObject t : list){
            switch(player1.hits(t.getHitBox())){
            case 1:
                player1.action(1, 0, (t.getHitBox().y + t.getHitBox().height));
                break;
            case 2:
                player1.action(2, (t.getHitBox().x + t.getHitBox().width + 1), 0);
                break;
            case 3:
                player1.action(3, (t.getHitBox().x - player1.getHitBox().width - 1), 0);
                break;
            case 4:
                player1.action(4, 0, (t.getHitBox().y - player1.getHitBox().height));
                System.out.println("AAA");
                break;  
            }
}
```

Here's how my sprite should look (and my top, bottom, right, left rectangles)

[image]

[image]

So here's my results. All colisions working fine except top collision I can't find what's wrong with game logic.
[image]

Comment: Code looks reasonable, I think we will need some more info. What happens when there should be a top collision? Are you sure that `hits` is returning -1 in this case? If so, what are the coordinates of the top bounding rectangle and the rectangle of the box it is colliding with at this time?

Comment: Use the ShapeRenderer API to draw your collision rectangles.  That might give you some better ideas about what is going wrong.